# Is there a standard keyboard shortcut for "Remember Me" in web forms?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, login, forms

I often find myself logging into websites like this:

- `Type in username`
- `Tab`
- `Type in password`
- *sigh* `Grab mouse and click "Remember Me"`
- `Enter`

Is there a standard shortcut I can use on most or all sites for checking this box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focus on the checkbox and press the `space` key.